# Aligning icon to the left in JTabbedPane in Nimbus Look and Feel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtabbedpane, nimbus

I was creating an application with `JTabbedPane` using Nimbus look and feel

I have used this code to place tabs:

```
pane.addTab("Welcome",new ImageIcon("resources\\1.png"),mainPanel,"Takes to the welcome page");
```

I want the icon to appear on the left and

[image: screenshot of the application]

Comment: So... did you try my answer? It was useful? Note this solution is L&F independent.

Comment: yupp. I didnt apply it to my app but i tried ur code and understood the concept. I liked the one with close button (similar to google chrome tab and other tabbed applications)
and yeah your solution is independent of look and feel because you are aligning it inside a panel and then adding it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set a custom component for rendering the tab title, through [JTabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(int index, Component component)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setTabComponentAt%28int,%20java.awt.Component%29) method:

> **Sets the component that is responsible for rendering the title for the
>   specified tab**. A null value means `JTabbedPane` will render the title
>   and/or icon for the specified tab. A non-null value means the
>   component will render the title and `JTabbedPane` will not render the
>   title and/or icon.
>
> Note: The component must not be one that the developer has already
>   added to the tabbed pane.

For instance you can do this:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Tab1");
label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.TRAILING); // Set the text position regarding its icon
label.setIcon(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon"));

JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.LEFT);
tabbedPane.addTab(null, new JPanel());
tabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(0, label); // Here set the custom tab component
```

**Screenshot 1:**

[image]

---

**Note:** using this feature you can set any `Component` as you wish. For instance you can make a `JPanel` with a `JButton` to close the tab:

```
final JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.LEFT);

ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
        for(int i = 0; i < tabbedPane.getTabCount(); i++) {
            if(SwingUtilities.isDescendingFrom(button, tabbedPane.getTabComponentAt(i))) {
                tabbedPane.remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};

JLabel label = new JLabel("Tab1", UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon"), JLabel.RIGHT);        
JButton closeButton = new JButton("X");
closeButton.addActionListener(actionListener);

JPanel tabComponent = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
tabComponent.add(label, BorderLayout.WEST);
tabComponent.add(closeButton, BorderLayout.EAST);

tabbedPane.addTab(null, new JPanel());
tabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(0, tabComponent); // Here set the custom tab component
```

**Screenshot 2:**

[image]

---

### Update

You might want to see this topic as well: [JTabbedPane: tab placement set to LEFT but icons are not aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308859/jtabbedpane-tab-placement-set-to-left-but-icons-are-not-aligned)

Comment: Tab component is CENTERED (regardless of how JPanel is constructed).
  
Do you know the way how to make inner panel (tab component) LEFT or RIGHT aligned without rewriting UI? Best when solution is LAF-safe.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler solution using HTML formatting. 
This is an example using html code to format text, but you can also format other elements within the tab:

```
final String PRE_HTML = "<html><p style=\"text-align: left; width: 230px\">"; 
final String POST_HTML = "</p></html>"; 

tabbedpane.setTitleAt(0, PRE_HTML + "your title" + POST_HTML);
tabbedpane.setTitleAt(2, PRE_HTML + "your title 2" + POST_HTML);
```