# Change tab look for JTabbedpane

Tags: java, jtabbedpane

How can I remove OR change colour of the border surrounding these tabs?

ALSO, is it possible to have the tab text change colour when the mouse is hovering over it?

[image]

Comment: Did you do some research?

Comment: @Prasad Yes. I found this page but I don't understand which is which.   http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CustomizingaJTabbedPaneLookandFeel.htm

Comment: Ok you can change the color of tab text on hovering a mouse. **setForeground()** is the method that you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have the tab text change colour when the mouse is
>   hovering over it?

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19787146/aligning-icon-to-the-left-in-jtabbedpane-in-nimbus-look-and-feel/19788356#19788356) you can set a custom component for rendering the tab title, through [JTabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(int index, Component component)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setTabComponentAt%28int,%20java.awt.Component%29) method. So you can do something like this:

```
final JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {            
    Color defaultColor;

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        JLabel label = (JLabel)e.getSource();
        defaultColor = label.getForeground();
        label.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        JLabel label = (JLabel)e.getSource();
        label.setForeground(defaultColor);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        JLabel label = (JLabel)e.getSource();
        Point point = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(label, e.getPoint(), tabbedPane);
        int selectedTab = tabbedPane.getUI().tabForCoordinate(tabbedPane, point.x, point.y);
        switch(e.getButton()){
            case MouseEvent.BUTTON2: tabbedPane.removeTabAt(selectedTab); break;
                default: tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(selectedTab);
        }                
    }

};

JLabel tab1 = new JLabel("Tab1");
tab1.addMouseListener(mouseListener);    

tabbedPane.addTab(null, new JPanel());
tabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(0, tab1);
```

> How can I remove OR change colour of the border surrounding these
>   tabs?

It's up to the Look and Feel decide the border color in this case. You should look into the L&F default properties and see if it's allowed change this color. For instance you could execute the following code to see L&F default properties (of course after setting the L&F):

```
for(Object key : UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().keySet()){
    System.out.println(key + " = " + UIManager.get(key));
}
```

Comment: So this link if not useful?  http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CustomizingaJTabbedPaneLookandFeel.htm

Comment: Not so much. I think these properties belong to Metal Look and Feel. If you're using another L&F the properties may change. @ManInMoon

Comment: Please take a look to the example. I've noticed that if you click on the `JLabel` the default tab change is lost. So I've added the `mouseClicked` event process. If you press the second button (wheel in my case) then the tab is removed, otherwise the tab become selected. @ManInMoon

Comment: I get an error on MouseAdapter on MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter(). Should this be a mouse listener?

Comment: So should I change :MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() to MouseAdapter mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {  ? OR have I got the wrong type of MouseListener?

Comment: @ManInMoon I'll give it a try but I'd need to know what L&F do you use. If you could see my updated answer and post a dump of L&F properties then I could lead you in right way (at least I'll try so).

Comment: It's a custom one developed by the platform I am writing my App for. Not sure how to view/open that