# Java JTabbedPane align Title text to center

Tags: java, swing, text, jtabbedpane

I am creating my own custom `JTabbedPane` object, with a simple little class that extends `JTabbedPane`. I have gotten a fair amount of this done, but recently found a problem, that being that the Title text for a tab does not auto align to the center of the Tab. And I want it to. Here is what it looks like:

[image: Just imagine that the tabs aren't aligned to the center]

As I said, it's just an extension of `JTabbedArea`, like so:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String name;
private final int width = 150, height = 50;
public ColoredTabs(String paneName,  int tabPlacement, String[] names, Color[] colors, JComponent[] components){
    super(tabPlacement);
    this.name = paneName;
    if(names.length != components.length || names.length != colors.length || components.length != colors.length){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The arguments for COMPONENTS, COLORS, and NAMES do not match up for '"+this.name+"'...");
    }
    setFont(Resources.getFont());
    setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        addTab(names[i], components[i]);
        setBackgroundAt(i, colors[i]);
        setIconAt(i, new ImageIcon(new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB)));

    }
}
```

The reason I go through the trouble of making the BufferedImage is to stretch the area of the Tab, for the ICON, maybe there is a way to center the text on the BufferedImage, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a custom tabbedPane you should be able to create Labels with a set alignment, then add them to the jTabbedPane, something like this:

```
//Create new label to be used as a tab name
JLabel tabLabel = new JLabel("Tab", JLabel.CENTER);
//add new label at set location
jTabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(0, tabLabel);
```

For more help please show us how you are creating the tabs.

Edit:
This may be relevant:
[Aligning icon to the left in JTabbedPane in Nimbus Look and Feel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19787146/aligning-icon-to-the-left-in-jtabbedpane-in-nimbus-look-and-feel)

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The best way is to put a JLabel in the area, and now I'm just using the JLabel to stretch the area of the Tab, thanks man.